# How to get exact page from .doc?

Tags: c#, string, ms-word, document

So i have a .doc with many pages and i want to open a specific page within C#. Here is the code i'm using to view the doc

```
string docPath = @"...\path\to\doc.doc";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(docPath);
string words = doc.Content.Text;
doc.Close();
app.Quit();
```

Comment: Don't post code just to say "I've posted code".  Whate you typed here has nothing to do with the question. What do you mean `open a specific page` and *what have you tried*? Open could mean "show the page in Word" or it could mean "get the text in tag page". Have you tried anything or are you asking for links to the docs and tutorials?

Comment: In any case, the Interop API closely matches what you can do with the menus and macros. There's a [GoTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.goto(v=office.14).aspx) method just like there's a `Go To` command. You could record a macro, and reuse the API methods in the generated VBA through Office Interop. Eg `var range = doc.GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage,WdGoToItem.wdGoToDirection)`